# write complex sql in laravel using database builder or eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel

How can i write this sql in laravel using database builder or eloquent?

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE product.CategoryID IN
 (SELECT CategoryID FROM (SELECT CategoryID FROM category where GroupCategoryID="12" AND category.IsActive="1" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10) t)
 AND product.IsActive="1" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3;
```

**UPDATE**

There are 3 tables: product, category, group_category
I want to get 3 random products by GroupCategoryID

The table product contain the CategoryID, the category table contains the GroupCategoryID.

The sql works for me ... but i want to rewrite my project in laravel and i want to use a modern approach

**UPDATE 2**

... this seems to work ... but it`s not so elegant :)

```
$result = DB::select('SELECT CategoryID FROM category where GroupCategoryID="4" AND category.IsActive="1"');
    $categories = array();
    foreach ($result as $r){
        array_push($categories, $r->CategoryID);
    }

    $randProducts = DB::table('product')
        ->whereIn('CategoryID', $categories)
        ->inRandomOrder()
        ->limit(3)
        ->get();
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you hit a particular roadblock?>

Comment: Why do you use `SELECT CategoryID FROM` twice?

Comment: We don't write your code for you. Give us what you have so far.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir why use select from twice? Because i don't want to pull all the data from DB. I want to pull only 10 CategoryID random from a specific GroupCategory then pull only 3 random products that have that category id

Comment: the idea is a want to get 3 random products from a specific group category.

Comment: look at `DB::rawSelect` or `DB::raw`.

Answer (score 0):

Elegant way for your SQL:

```
$categoryIDs = Category::where('IsActive', 1)
    ->where('GroupCategoryID', 12)
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('rand()'))
    ->take(10)
    ->select('CategoryID')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('CategoryID')
    ->toArray();

$products = Product::whereIn('CategoryID', $categoryIDs)
    ->where('IsActive', 1)
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('rand()'))
    ->take(3)
    ->get();
```

Comment: In the first query you don't need `->select('CategoryID')->get()` and `->toArray()`.